# Single-Purpose SSH account, exclusively for Reverse Port Forwarding

Tags: ssh, user-management, port-forwarding

On my Debian system, I'd like to create a user that is *only* allowed to do a Reverse Port Forward from their machine to my server, but I'm not sure how to create a limited user specifically for this purpose.

For example, we'll call my server 'Sam' and my laptop 'Luke'. I'd like a user on Luke to be able to execute a reverse port forward ssh command to Sam, so that port 4321 on Sam is tunneled to port 4321 on Luke. For example:

```
ssh -fnR 4321:localhost:4321 -l limitedUser Sam
```

How can I create a user on Sam that is only allowed to execute this command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The document I always look to on complicated SSH stuff is this one on [doing passphraseless SSH right](http://wiki.hands.com//howto/passphraseless-ssh/).

The important things are to restrict with `command=` on `.ssh/authorized_keys` and to set their shell to /bin/nologin. I'm not sure off the top of my head what the name of the reverse forward command would be. You might not even need one, in which case just make the command nologin or logout or something.

Comment: that's going to help a lot. I didn't realize the authorized_keys file format had so many options. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To be more precise just add permitopen="host:port" ssh-rsa yourrsakey. That will restrict port forwarding to one host:port only

Comment: This restricts *local* port forwarding. The OP is asking about *remote* port forwarding.

Answer (score 0):

You might also be interested in the **Match** keyword in sshd_config: http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=sshd_config

It might be better if you have lots of users with similar privileges, and safer in some contexts, since /etc/sshd_config is only root-writable, yet ~/.ssh/ is not ALWAYS read-only for users.